# am start com.redbend.vdmc/com.htc.omadm.test.TestMainActivity lawmo lock

Tags: unlock

i have an sprint htc one and i am using a tmobile sim card and everything has
been working fine,  untill i went into the developer menu by typing in terminal 
am start com.redbend.vdmc/com.htc.omadm.test.TestMainActivity which brings up the  i 
secret menu, i choose api then when i was scrolling through the menu i accidently selected 
lawmo lock 1234, now no matter what i do i cant get past this screen that asked for a lock code which i dont have,  ive wiped and reinstalled the rom and even ruu ed stock rom nothing gets past this screen,  except if i install a aosp rom, but i need a sense rom to be able to 
search for gsm networks since its a cdma phone.   can anyone help

Answer (score 0):

Delete omadm apk from twrp, im unable to remove the lock, just bypassed it
Install htc dumlock, open file browser-system-app-delete htc omadm.....lock will be bypassed in 4.1.2, if  4.3, delete lockscreen apk too